# Let $y = f(x)$ be the particular solution to the differential equation $ \frac{dy}{dx} $=$y^2$ with the initial condition $f(3) = 1$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $y = f(x)$ be the particular solution to the differential equation $ \frac{dy}{dx} $=$y^2$ with the initial condition $f(3) = 1$. Which of the following gives an expression for $f(x)$ and the domain for which the solution is valid?

A.)   $f(x)= \frac{1}{4-x} $ for $x < 4$

B.)   $f(x)= \frac{1}{4-x} $ for $x > 4$

C.)   $f(x)= \frac{4x-1}{x} $ for $x > 0$

D.)   $f(x)= \frac{4x-1}{x} $ for $x \ne 0$

Would the answer be A since the equation is then valid for when $x=3$? And it couldn't be C or D, as those don't satisfy $f(3)=1$, right?

Comment: You did not even need to solve the differential equation to obtain the answer. Your reasoning is correct

Comment: ahhh~ thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple separable ODE
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2$$
Separate variables,
$$\frac{1}{y^2} \frac{dy}{dx} = 1$$
Integrating both sides,
$$\int y^{-2} dy = x+ c_1$$
So
$y^{-1} = -x + c_1'$ (with $c_1' = -c_1+c_2$). Thus, we get that
$$y = \frac{1}{c_1' - x}$$
Since $y(3)=1$ we then immediately see that ${c_1'} = {4}$.
We find the solution
$$y = \frac{1}{4-x}$$
Since $3 < 4$ we then get that A) is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer solved the differential equation correctly, but your reasoning in your question is correct.

It cannot be option B.) since that function is not defined for $x=3$, so $f(3)$ does not exist.

It cannot be option C.) since $f(3)=\frac{4(3)-1}{3}=\frac{11}{3}\neq1$.

It cannot be option D.), at $x=3$ it is the same as option C.), so $f(3)\neq1$.

That leaves only option A.), which must be the answer.